# Film where a character vanishes while splashing in a puddle of water

Tags: story-identification, movie

Trying to find the title of a film where a character vanishes while happily splashing in a puddle of water. I've dreamed of this particular scene the last few nights and it's driving me insane to not be able to locate it. The scene takes place at night, and it feels as if the character was actually celebrating being there. **Slaughterhouse 5** comes to mind, and so does **The Time Traveler's Wife**, but I'm really not sure and have no access to the actual films to check the scene out. It could also very easily be a scene from a completely unrelated film or TV show [non-science fiction or fantasy]

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: I think there are multiple possibilities so narrowing it down as best you can will be necessary for us to help you find it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This scene is a good match for one in Twelve Monkeys directed by Terry Gilliam from 1995.

There is a scene with Madeleine Stow and Bruce Willis in a forest at night. Willis is happily splashing up and down in a large puddle talking about happily spending time with various animals while police with torches run to catch up with them. the scene ends with Bruce Willis character vanishing into thin air. In fact he is time travelling which is why it could be easy to confuse with Slaughterhouse Five.

Here is trailer. There is a very short clip from the scene in question at exactly 1 minute. See if it rings a bell.

Comment: If anyone can find the full scene I would appreciate it. I havent managed to spot it on youtube yet.

Comment: the movie is god-tier. the series, like all post 2012 series, is utter trash tbh.

Comment: THAT'S IT! How could I have forgotten it was from one of the movies I love the most? Thank you Skyjack, your memory has saved my day.

Comment: @Chris glad to be of service. I agree, it is a very good film.